# Wygwam not stripping markup

Tags: wygwam, strip-html, markup

Since Wygwam 2.3.1 it's supposed to have "Set the forcePasteAsPlainText CKEditor config setting to 'Yes' by default" (pasted from [release notes](http://pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/releasenotes)). But I'm still getting a lot of junk code (inline styles, Word markup, the whole shebang).

Is this happening for other people as well? I've even tried adding it manually as a config setting, but that didn't make any difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this is making my client's life miserable.

Comment: Do you have Wygwam 2.7 installed?

Comment: Is the markup getting through in all browsers (and operating systems) or just one?

Answer (score 1):

Wygwam sucks at removing formatting. I have exhausted all resources in trying to find an adequate solution. Luckily I have found 2 simple plugins that will take care of this for you, depending on what you're trying to do.

**Two Scenarious**

1. You're using WYGWAM to show an H1 and want to keep the Spell Checker in place but want to lose the `<p>` tag it outputs. Use PtoBR: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/paragraph-to-br
2. You're using WYGWAM to output a "summary" on a blog listing and want everything remove but a few things, then I'd use Super Geekery Tag Stripper: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/supergeekery-tag-stripper

Both are quite useful depending on your needs. There are other strippers out there like Hacksaw, but those are two that I absolutely recommend.

**One last thing you can do:**

Use the "paste from word" functionality button? I use that ALL the time and saves a lot of headaches. Works with getting rid of embedded styles in just about anything too, not just Microsoft Word related issues.